# attempt to index local 'f2' ERROR in lua

Tags: lua

I'm trying to code a game. I want to write the high score to a file to save it permanently.
I tried the code below.. But then I got an error "Attempt to index local 'f2' (a nil value)"
How to rectify this error? 
Also .. I tried many other combinations to write new highscore to file.. but every time I got stuck with some or the other problem :/ . (This is also something I think should work). If not so, then can some one please provide me the code for writing new score to file and the retrieving the data when game is over.

Code:

```
local path = system.pathForFile( "scoredata.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory )

function read_score()
local f1 = io.open (path, "w")
local f2 = io.open(path, "r")
highScore = f2:read( "*n" )
if highScore==nil  -- Initial value of score is 0 and "score" is the in-game score counter.
    then highScore=0
end
if score>highScore
        then
    highScore=score 
    f1:write(highScore)     
    disp_permScore()
    else
    disp_permScore() 
end
io.close(f1)
io.close(f2)
end

function disp_permScore()  -- Function to display the highscore
text_display2= display.newText("BEST: " .. highScore, 0, 0, "Helvetica", 90)
    text_display2.x = centerX
    text_display2.y = centerY + 80
    text_display2.alpha=1 
end

function gameOver() --this function is invoked after game is over
read_score()
local bg= display.newImage("bgpng.png")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`f2` is nil because `io.open` failed. Use this to see the error message:

```
local f2 = assert(io.open(path, "r"))
```

However, note that the previous call to `io.open` destroyed the file you're trying to read.

Comment: It says "Permission denied" .. How to rectify this?

Comment: @TimeThief, there you go. Check the path and the permissions. Not a Lua problem, really.

Comment: How to check? I mean I have added `local path = system.pathForFile( "scoredata.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory )` in the code ..

Comment: @TimeThief File system permissions. The user running that script is not allowed to open the file in question. And as lhf said the `io.open(path, "w")` has already truncated the file so it has no contents to read when you try to read from the `f2` file handle (if you were even getting such a file handle in the first place).